# drivers to communicate with MS SQL database using php 5.5

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble finding drivers that support PHP 5.5 when communicating with a MS SQL database.  I've [found Mssql supports up to 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php) ("This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.") and the [SQLSRV drivers only support up to 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php).  I understand there is an "[experimental](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790641/sql-server-driver-for-php-5-5)" version supporting 5.5, but said drivers need to be PCI compliant.  Would my only solution be to downgrade my php version?  Any assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are all still waiting for Microsoft to respond and publish a PHP 5.5 driver for SQL Server. Here is the [Connect entry for this request](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790641/sql-server-driver-for-php-5-5).

There is an unofficial driver compiled for PHP 5.5 that [you can find here](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/discussions/441706) (please read the thread).

Comment: oh microsoft. I did see that only issue is the pci compliance.  guess ill build what i can with the unofficial driver thanks!

Comment: I can attest that this works, I've employed this to get PHP 5.5 + SQL Server 2014 working with Brandoo Wordpress.